# DateTime.Format() Documentation example causes exception

Tags: apex, soql, query, datetime, date

I'm trying to get a DateTime to format into a value to be used in a dynamic query. For some reason, the documentation snippet on how to format a DateTime for a query is giving me an exception.

Im trying to run this anonymous apex snippet:

```apex
System.debug(DateTime.now().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ'));
```

The format string I'm using is specified on [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm).

The exception I'm getting back is:

> Line: 1, Column: 1
>   System.StringException: Unrecognized format: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ

If I remove the `T`, the string is accepted, but isn't in the right format to query on.

```apex
System.debug(DateTime.now().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ssZ'));
```

Output:

> 2016-03-75 04:01:33-0400

Additionally, if I take the date literals provided on the page, and use them in a query, the query accepts the string, but still won't let me try to format a DateTime into the same Date Format as the accepted Date Literal.

Example:

```
[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Some_Date__c > 1999-01-01T23:01:01Z]
```

Comment: Why are you formatting DateTime values instead of just binding directly to the variable?

Comment: The formatted date string is being used later on in a partner api query operation, so I can't use a bind variable inside the query string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550709/salesforce-apex-iso-timestamp-format-function)

Use:

```apex
system.debug(Datetime.now().formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\''));
```

The esteemed Mr Ballinger also recommends the following, but it is wrapped in double quotes and slower, so I would probably not use it, myself.

```apex
system.debug(JSON.serialize(Datetime.now()));
```

Answer (score 5):

You are linking into formats used in SOQL engine. Please refer to [Apex reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) and [Java SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more advanced formats.